# Calculate time interval between successive visits in SAS

Tags: datetime, sas, group-by

I have repeated measures in long format, such as

id  visit   date

1   1   1990-12-16

1   2   1991-01-12

1   3   1991-09-01

2   1   2000-12-12

2   2   2001-11-30

I wanted to calculate the time interval (in weeks) between successive visits. For each visits, it will be date of visit i minus data of visit i-1 [hence, interval=0 for visit=1 for all subjects]

I used lag function, but what it did was the difference between time with the previous column (which was another date). How can I make it column wise taking care of id.

I used the following code:
    data data1;

```
set data;

by id;

if first.id then interval=0;

else interval=lag(date)/7; *divided by 7 as I wanted the interval to be in weeks;

run;
```

Any help please? If it is a repeated post, please guide me to that. I haven't found anything exactly like this however. Thanks.

PS: I don't know how to have the data in data format. Please help me without flagging it!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the lag date in conditional code, so take it out of the conditional statements.

Assuming the date is text, you can use input() function to convert it to a SAS date.

```
data data1; 
set data; 
by id; 
date_sas=input(date, anydtdte.);
interval_lag=lag(date_sas)/7;
if first.id then interval=0; 
else interval=interval_lag; 
run;
```

Comment: Thanks @reese, but it still calculates by rows, and NOT by columns as I wanted. Any further help?

Comment: You need to post a better example of how your data is structured.  Most likely you'll want an array then instead.

Comment: Do you want the `dif` function rather than `lag`? `Lag` returns the value from the previous observation (row) while `dif` returns the difference between the current and previous observations. Reese's first statement is true for `dif` as well as `lag`; you should avoid using these functions within if statements.

Comment: Yes, dif function worked...thanks a lot @ArchStanton

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still loking for an answer for this question, but this should do the trick:

I read in the data this way:

```
data test;
input id visit date :yymmdd.; *this is how you tell SAS to read the date as a date;
format date yymmdd10.;

datalines;
1 1 1990-12-16
1 2 1991-01-12
1 3 1991-09-01
2 1 2000-12-12
2 2 2001-11-30
;
run;
```

Then to calculate what you wanted:

```
data data1; 
set test; 
by id; 
retain date_n;
if first.id then do;
interval = 0; 
date_n = date;
end;
else do;
interval = (date - date_n)/7; 
date_n = date;
end;
run;
```

Hope this helps!